# fcitx's candidates window not show when using super search

Tags: gnome, fcitx

I installed ubuntu-gnome-desktop, fcitx works well but when I use super search, the candidates window not show.

[image: http://i67.tinypic.com/30subzn.png]

Comment: dconf-editor's search box also can not active IM.